# can i make this class thread safe via immutable object?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a class in which i have 2 people which check balance and withdraw money from a common account .. i have made the the transaction thread safe via `synchronized` keyword but it has a lot of overhead , i have read about immutable objects and thread safety they provide . but i am unable to make this class thread safe via immutable object

code :

```
final class bank implements Runnable
{
private final int balance,min_balance;

bank(int bal,int mbal)
{
  this.balance=bal;
  this.min_balance=mbal;
}
@Override
public void run()
{
   transaction();

}
public void transaction()
{
   if(checkBalance()> min_balance)
    {
     System.out.println("checkin is done by : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()
             +" and Balance left in the account is : "+checkBalance()); 
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is going to sleep ...");
    try{

       Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); }
       catch(Exception e){
       }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Woke up ..");
    withdraw();  
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" has made the withdrawl ..");
   }
   else{
      lowBalance();   
   }
}

int checkBalance()
{
   return balance;
 }
 void lowBalance()
 {
     System.out.println("balance is not adequate");
 }

void withdraw()
{
   balance=balance-20;  //this wont work as balance is private
}

}

public class ryanmonica {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   bank obj=new bank(100,20);
   Thread t1=new Thread(obj);
   Thread t2=new Thread(obj);
   t1.setName("Ryan");
   t2.setName("Monica");
   t1.start();
   t2.start(); 

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *immutable* object's state never changes. Since you need state change in your instance (`balance` and `minBalance` are changing), you need to use *synchronization* mechanism.

Immutable objects are thread-safe because they don't allow state change in their instances.

Comment: ok i got your point .. so is there any practical use of immutable object in thread safety ?

Comment: @Amol immutable object is useful because you can ensure the objects you are holding will always be the same value, so the program can be better reasoned. i don't really think immutable data can provide magical advantages in terms of multithreading, since if you really need to change something, you will need to have an object ultimately to hold states and the states are required to be mutable. if you need to fully utilize immutable data, systematic functional programming is a better approach, which has been a problem from another domain.

Comment: @Amol - Yes. C2 JIT compiler will remove synchronization around immutable instances and thus no code to generate memory barriers will be emitted by the JVM which will improve performance because JVM can pass immutable objects to multiple threads and yet not worry about changes made by one thread affecting other threads.

Comment: thanks guys ... i was really confused with immutable and thread safety